# ExtJS 4 Grid not working with Ctrl-F in Firefox

Tags: javascript, extjs4

I can not get Firefox's find feature (Ctrl-F) to work with the Ext.grid.Panel. I'd like to be able to use it to find strings in the grid. How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this css (after ext-all.css is loaded):

```
.x-grid3-row td,
.x-grid3-summary-row td,
.x-grid3-cell-text,
.x-grid3-hd-text,
.x-grid3-hd,
.x-grid3-row {
    -moz-user-select:inherit;
    -khtml-user-select:text;
}
```

See also:[condor's solution](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?22218-Text-Selections-in-Grid-cell/page2) For a more refined approach.

Note:* This also enables text selection in the grid.